# Multiple sed vs sed using pipe (Is "sed -e cmd1 -e cmd2" the same as "sed -e cmd1 | sed -e cmd2"?)

Tags: sed

What is the difference between these two?

- `sed -e 'script1' -e 'script2' file`
- `sed 'script1' file | sed 'script2'`

I was expecting them to be the same, but it appears they're not.

Here's an example how they're different:

```
$ cat test
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    11786 nick  138u  IPv6 858395      0t0  TCP localhost:46091->localhost:9092 (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    11786 nick  142u  IPv6 860196      0t0  TCP localhost:46093->localhost:9092 (CLOSE_WAIT)

$  sed 'G;G' test | sed '/^$/d'
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    11786 nick  138u  IPv6 858395      0t0  TCP localhost:46091->localhost:9092 (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    11786 nick  142u  IPv6 860196      0t0  TCP localhost:46093->localhost:9092 (CLOSE_WAIT)

$  sed -e 'G;G;' -e '/^$/d;G' test
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME



java    11786 nick  138u  IPv6 858395      0t0  TCP localhost:46091->localhost:9092 (CLOSE_WAIT)



java    11786 nick  142u  IPv6 860196      0t0  TCP localhost:46093->localhost:9092 (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

The diffence IS the spacing. Like I said, I would have thought them to be the same, what gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed -e script1 -e script2` is not the same as `sed [-e] script1 | sed [-e] script2`. See example:

```
[STEP 101] # printf '%s\n' 1 2 3 4
1
2
3
4
[STEP 102] # printf '%s\n' 1 2 3 4 | sed -e n -e d # delete line 2, 4, 6, ...
1
3
[STEP 103] # printf '%s\n' 1 2 3 4 | sed n | sed d
[STEP 104] #
```

*STEP 103* prints nothing since the last `sed d` would delete everything.

---

`sed -e script1 -e script2` is usually the same as `sed -e "script1<NEWLINE>script2"`. Maybe you're confused with this?